# Partial configuration parsing in case of malformed input

Tags: rust, serde

I have a Rust application using TOML files for its configuration and serde for deserialization. Config files are user input, it can be malformed, I want my app to be resilient enough to load even with malformed configuration files, using default values for the variables that couldn't be parsed.

Considering the following struct

```
#[derive(Deserialize)]
struct User {
    name: String,
    age: i32,
}
```

In case of malformed input, I want my configuration to be `name = "Steven"` and `age = 21`.
Considering the following TOML

```
[User]
name = "John"
age = "Thirty-two"
```

Serde will crash saying that a String can't be parsed as an i32. The name is correct, I can use it. The age can't be parsed so I take the default value of 21. I tried using `#[serde(default)]` but doesn't prevent a parsing crash.

Comment: Silently using a different value from what the user specified is going to lead to surprise and thus will be a much worse experience than your program crashing and telling them they got a configuration error. You'd probably best use [`toml::Value`](https://docs.rs/toml/latest/toml/enum.Value.html) and implement `From<toml::Value> for User` if you really, **really** want to go down that path.

Answer (score 0):

Using `#[serde(default)]` will give you the default value of the type which in the case of i32 would be zero.

For this case using `.unwrap_or()` and then put in the default values incase of error. [Playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=6f464410ddb814aad86f886e35008e98)

```
use serde::*;
use toml::*;

#[derive(Deserialize)]
struct User {
    name: String,
    age: i32,
}

fn main() {
    let User: User = toml::from_str(
        r#"
    [User]
    name = "John"
    age = "Thirty-two
  "#,
    )
    .unwrap_or(User {
        name: "Steven".to_string(),
        age: 21,
    });
}
```

Comment: I don't think this is what OP wants, namely it doesn't adhere to *"The name is correct, I can use it. The age can't be parsed so I take the default value of 21"*.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but cafce25 is correct, I can't keep "John" with this solution

Answer (score -2):

I don't know of a better way other than to manually write the default and deserialization methods for each field that's optional, which will handle the cases where the field is either missing or malformed. (I've switched to json below because quite frankly I have no idea how TOML works.)

```rust
fn default_age() -> i32 {
    21
}

fn de_age<'de, D>(deserializer: D) -> Result<i32, D::Error>
where
    D: Deserializer<'de>,
{
    Ok(i32::deserialize(deserializer).unwrap_or_else(|_| default_age()))
}

#[derive(Debug, Deserialize)]
struct User {
    name: String,
    #[serde(default="default_age", deserialize_with = "de_age")]
    age: i32,
}

fn main() {
    let users: Vec<User> = serde_json::from_str::<Vec<User>>(
        r#"[{"name": "A", "age": "five"}, {"name": "B", "age": 6}, {"name": "C"}]"#,
    )
    .unwrap();
    println!("{users:?}");
}
```

```
[User { name: "A", age: 21 }, User { name: "B", age: 6 }, User { name: "C", age: 21 }]
```

Comment: Deserializer errors are in general not recoverable. `.deserialize(deserializer).unwrap_or_else` might put the deserializer into a state where it can no longer continue. For example `{"name": "D", "age": {}}` will not work with the code.